# How to make byobu output the complete history directly to buffer?

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, byobu

It is possible to enter some sort of scrolling back mode with some keys. But I wonder if we can directly output to the buffer and use the scrolling of the terminal app.

I noticed it is possible, because the byobu installed on my vultr VPS does. But anywhere else it does not behave like this. So I guess there must be some options hidden.

Comment: Not sure what is the exact question. But if you have long output, you can pipe it through `less` to get "scroll" over that buffer. It is automatic sometimes, but you can suppress it by piping the output through `cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can save the entire contents of your current Byobu window or split to a buffer, using the hot key <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>.

```
Shift-F7                     Save history to $BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: `alt`+`F7` or `shift`+`F7` would open `vim` on my old machine (Ubuntu 14.04), I was not able to do it on my new machine with `Ubuntu 16.04` and `byobu 5.106`.  Do you have any clue?

Comment: Can I change output path to `$PWD/printscreen` instead of  `$BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen` ?